# Conditional select data that is refresh from error on new row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an application that writes data to a database.  If some record is in error and then user amends with some new data it will add a new row that will display processing status as 'Refresh'.

How can I write an oracle query to search for status 'Error' but return if something was 'Refresh'?

The logic would be select all data that have 'Error' if for same Process_ID status have 'Refresh' then select refresh only.

For example here is some sample data of what it looks like, I want to return only rows 2, 4, 6, and 7

```
+------+---------+-------------+
|Row_ID|ProcessID|ProcessStatus|
+------+---------+-------------+
|1     |123      |Error        |
|2     |123      |Refresh      | 
|3     |456      |Error        |
|4     |456      |Refresh      | 
|5     |789      |Error        |
|6     |789      |Refresh      | 
|7     |987      |Error        |
+------+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Exists` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.processstatus = 'Refresh' and
      exists (select 1 
              from t t2
              where t2.ProcessID = t.ProcessID and t2.processstatus = 'Error'
             )
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.processstatus = 'Error' and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ProcessID = t.ProcessID and t2.processstatus = 'Refresh'
                 );
```

Or, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by processid
                                order by case processstatus when 'Refresh' then 1 else 2 end
                               ) as seqnum,
             sum(case when processstatus = 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by processid) as cnt_error
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If greater `row_id` values denote newer entries, then you only need to get the maximum `row_id` for each `processid` and then join to the table:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select processid, max(row_id) row_id
  from tablename
  group by processid
) g on t.row_id = g.row_id
```

Comment: another great option thank you, I'll experiment for the faster query results

Answer (score 0):

If there are at most two certain options (namely `Error` and `Refresh`) for `ProcessStatus` 
just use the following with `in` operator

```
select *
  from tab 
 where ( ProcessID, ProcessStatus ) in
  (
   select ProcessID, max(ProcessStatus)
     from tab
    group by ProcessID
  )
 order by row_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/HDJHT8362)</kbd>